# pytorch: how to multiply 3d tensor with 2d tensor

Tags: pytorch

I got a 3D tensor `three` and a 2D tensor `two`, which need to be multiplied. For example, the dimensions are:

```
three.shape = 4x100x700
two.shape = 4x100
```

Output shape should be:

```
output.shape = 4x100x700
```

So basically, in `output[a,b]` there should be 700 scalars which were computed by multiplying all 700 scalars from `three[a,b]` with the single scalar from `two[a,b]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add an extra dimension to `two`:

```
output = three * two.unsqueeze(-1)
```

There are alternative syntax, e.g.:

```
output = three * two[..., None]
```